# init block in Kotlin with 2+ constructors

Tags: android, kotlin

Found that `init {}` block is executed before secondary constructor.

So basically i have two constructors (`primary` and `secondary`). Primary is used just for initializing simple view. Secondary - trying to populate editViews with data. After `secondary` constructor im expecting that `init` block will be executed.

Is there a way to make it happen?

```
class EditView(val context: Context){
    constructor(context: Context, title: String): this(context) {
        // Executes after init block
    }

    init {
        // Ran before secondary constructor
        // Code for initializing my view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this, since the `init` blocks are essentially the body of the primary constructor (and so are any inline property initializers). This means that it will run when you call into the primary from the secondary with `this(context)`, and only then can you run the code in your secondary constructor.

Having ran the primary constructor first ensures that your instance is already in a valid, constructed state for when the primary constructor's body runs - for example, non-nullable properties have a non-null value, etc.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!